# Getting Chatter to include Opportunity name on mentions

Tags: visualforce, chatter, chatter-conversation

Here's a fun one.  We are using Chatter in order to notify team members as to new opportunities.  The problem comes when a member gets mentioned and the email sent out includes the subject line of "Joan Salesforce mentioned you in a post"...how can I get this notification to send with the subject line similar to when someone comments on the opportunity (e.g. "Joan Salesforce also commented on a post on Opportunity: VisualSalesForceApex - 2013)?

Answer (score 1):

I was discussing this very topic with a colleague earlier today. As far as I know Salesforce generated chatter emails are not configurable.

Your only option will be to roll your own... The 2 biggest problems I can think of would be:

- you could exhaust your daily email limit if you are a big organisation
- Users will receive 2 emails about the same thing, or you will have to disable chatter email altogether. Disabling chatter emails could be a very big problem all on its own.

Comment: my org is not very large, so we're a respectable distance away from the email limits.  Would you know how to go about programming it, or possibly point me to a resource that would guide me?